# Can I get the translation / scaling of an svg object?

Tags: javascript, svg

I am writing a symbol recognition service which I want to extend to complete formula recognition. This allows people to write a formula and then get LaTeX back. As soon as the user has finished writing, I store the written stuff as an SVG with the template

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>

<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   version="1.1"
   width="400"
   height="400"
   xml:space="preserve"
   viewBox="0 0 {{ width }} {{ height }}"
   preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">

{{ path }}
{{ dots }}
</svg>
```

This gets included via

```
<object data="123456.svg"
        type="image/svg+xml"
        id="canvas"
        style="width:400px;height:400px;border:1px solid black;"></object>
```

(see for [example with old template without centering](http://www.martin-thoma.de/write-math/view/?raw_data_id=324196))

Now I have some JavaScript code which allows users to segment the formulas. But this code needs adjustments when the SVG centers itself with the viewBox / preserveAspectRatio.

How can I get the necessary values (translation and scaling factors) to adjust my code?

(I found `MDN SVG Svg DOM interface`, but this seems not to work when I include the svg in an object tag. I cannot include the svg in an image tag as I need to work with contents of the SVG.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVG elements have a function called `getScreenCTM()` which returns the matrix used to transform a coordinate in SVG space to a coordinate in screen space.

You want to do the opposite direction.  Luckily, all SVGMatrix objects have a function called `inverse()` which inverts the matrix.

All you need to do is take your `clientX` and `clientY` coordinates from your mouse event and run them through the inverted matrix.  You will then have the corresponding SVG coordinate for that point.

```
<html>

<object data="324196.svg"
        type="image/svg+xml"
        id="canvas"
        style="width:400px;height:400px;border:1px solid black;" onclick="calc()"></object>

</body>

<script>

canvas.addEventListener("load",function(){
   document.getElementById("canvas").contentDocument.addEventListener("click", calc);
});

function calc(evt)
{
    var svg = document.getElementById("canvas").contentDocument.firstChild;

    var  point = svg.createSVGPoint();
    point.x = evt.clientX;
    point.y = evt.clientY;
    point = point.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());

    var circle = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
    circle.setAttribute("cx", point.x);
    circle.setAttribute("cy", point.y);
    circle.setAttribute("r", "5");
    circle.setAttribute("fill", "red");
    circle.setAttribute("fill-opacity", "0.5");
    svg.appendChild(circle);
}

</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Also, for your `getContainedPaths() ` function, if you do a paths[i].getBBox() call, you may find the return result useful. :)

Comment: Thank you very much :-) By the way, do you even care when you get a bounty?

Comment: Do you mean getting the "accepted" green check mark and/or upvotes?  It is always preferred.  But you can't force someone to do it, so there's no point in getting upset when they don't.  It's not the main reason I am here answering questions.

Comment: And most of my answers are in the SVG tag. It's not a tag that generates lots of points or badges. :)

Comment: No, I did not mean accepting / upvotes. I mean a bounty. Once in a while I give bounties to fast and good answers (after accepting and upvoting it) to show the authors that I appreciate what they wrote. However, for people like you who have more than 10k points I am not sure if they really care when they get bounties.

Comment: Oh I see. That's totally up to you.

Comment: Sadly, not totally. SO only allows me to give bounties after 2 days. I hope I will not forget it.